# Given a string, compute recursively (no loops)

Tags: java, string

Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of times lowercase "hi" appears in the string

countHi("xxhixx") -> 1

countHi("xhixhixx") -> 2

countHi("hi") -> 1

```
public class Tester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int count = countHi("xxhixx");


        System.out.println("countHi: " + count);


    }

    public static int countHi(String s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int spot = s.indexOf("hi");

        if(spot > 0)
        {   
            String nextString = s.substring(spot + 2);
            return 1 + countHi(nextString);
        }
        return 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? I assume soem inputs return a numer that is too large by one? You don't account for a string that is larger than 0 but does not contain "hi" at all. Your method would return 1 where it shoudl return 0. You can remove teh check for length == 0 and instead distinguish (spot >= 0) -> recursive call + 1 and (spot < 0) -> return 0

Answer (score 3):

Should work with the following code:

```
public static int countHi(String s) {
    return countHi(s, 0);
}

public static int countHi(String s, int pos) {
    if (s.length() - pos < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    int result = 0;
    if(s.charAt(pos) == 'h' && s.charAt(pos + 1) == 'i') {
        result++;
    }

    return result + countHi(s, pos + 2);
}
```

Comment: Updated code without substring.

Comment: Strings can't be indexed as if they were a char array.  You can use `charAt()`, or convert to a char array using `toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  F(x[1...n]) = 
     if the string starts with "hi" then 1 + F(x[3...n])
     else F(x[2...n])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function will need a parameter that tells it where in the string to start looking.  If the character at that position is `'h'`, then check whether the one after it is `'i'`; if it is, you've found a match.

For the recursive call that checks the remainder of the string, pass the index of the next character if it wasn't `'i'`, or two characters ahead if it was.

(I'm giving just a description instead of actual code because this looks like a homework question.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int recCountHi(String str) {        
    if(str.length() < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(str.substring(0, 2).equals("hi")) {            
        return 1 + recCountHi(str.substring(1));            
    } 
    return recCountHi(str.substring(1));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.indivunet.utils;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Tester
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printCountFor("xxhixx", 1);
        printCountFor("", 0);
        printCountFor("xxhixxhihi", 3);
        printCountFor(null, 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void countHi()
    {
        assertAndPrint("xxhixx", 1);
        assertAndPrint("", 0);
        assertAndPrint("xxhixxhihi", 3);
        assertAndPrint(null, 0);
    }

    private void assertAndPrint(String string, int expectedCount)
    {
        int count = printCountFor(string, expectedCount);
        assertEquals(expectedCount, count);
    }

    private static int printCountFor(String string, int expected)
    {
        int count = countHi(string);
        System.out.println("string: \"" + string + "\" expected: " + expected + " count: " + count);
        return count;
    }

    public static int countHi(String s)
    {
        if (s == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int count = 0;
        boolean hiSpotted = true;
        while (hiSpotted)
        {
            int startOfNextHi = s.indexOf("hi");
            hiSpotted = startOfNextHi >= 0;
            if (!hiSpotted)
            {
                return count;
            }
            s = s.substring(startOfNextHi + 2);
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```